# Add leading 0 to integer in bash after doing arithmetic

Tags: bash

I want to always have 2-digit outputs (e.g., `03`, `94`):

```
i=1; ls | while read l; do mv "$l" name$i; let i=$i+1; done
```

For instance, setting `i=01` and doing an addition may not return a 2-digit output.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: You'll want the builtin `printf` command: at an interactive prompt, type `help printf`

Comment: What happen for 100,101,102...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` command lets you specify number formatting with padding to a specified width. As already noted in comments, [using `ls` is unnecessary and even harmful here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
i=1
for l in *; do
    printf -v new "name%02i" "$i"
    mv "$l" "$new"
    let i=$i+1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `rename`, a.k.a. **Perl rename** to you.

```
rename --dry-run -N "01" '$_=$N' *
```

**Sample Output**

```
'file-a' would be renamed to '01'
'file-b' would be renamed to '02'
'file-c' would be renamed to '03'
'file-d' would be renamed to '04'
'file-e' would be renamed to '05'
'file-f' would be renamed to '06'
'file-g' would be renamed to '07'
'file-h' would be renamed to '08'
'file-i' would be renamed to '09'
'file-j' would be renamed to '10'
'file-k' would be renamed to '11'
'file-l' would be renamed to '12'
'file-m' would be renamed to '13'
'file-n' would be renamed to '14'
```

If that looks good, run it again without the `--dry-run` option to actually rename files.

This has the following benefits:

- It will not clobber any files whose new names would clash,
- you can call it with `--dry-run` to check what it *would* do, **without actually doing anything**,
- your new name can be as complicated a Perl expression/program as you like,
- it will rename across directories and create any intermediate directories as necessary, if you add the `-p` switch

---

**Note**: Install on macOS with **homebrew**:

```
brew install rename
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in 0{7..9} {10..12}; do echo $i; done
```

I think it will help you

Comment: I think this helps you: `{07..12}`