# Read filenames using for loop in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, sh

In my folder, filenames are like this:

```
A00001
A00002
.
.
.
A08525
```

I want to add this file name as an argument:

```
max = 8525
for i in `seq 2 $max`
do
    python script.py -r filename 
done
```

I tried like this:

```
max = 8525
for i in `seq 2 $max`
do
    python script.py -r "A0000$i" #But this work for 1-9 like wise for A000 it will work for 100-999
done
```

I can not do

```
for file in A*; 
do 
    echo "$file"; done
done
```

Because the folder has the same file with three different extensions, like `A0000.txt`, `A0000.pdf`, `A0000.png`, and I want to input only `A0000` as an argument.

How can I write the for loop so that I can read all filenames?

Comment: How about `for file in A*; do echo "$file"; done`?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: Thanks, this I though but actually folder has same file with three different extensions. like `A0000.txt A0000.pdf A0000.png` and I want to input only `A0000` without extension

Comment: `max=8525`; spaces are not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844645/add-leading-0-to-integer-in-bash-after-doing-arithmetic

Comment: Your examples have five digits but then a lot of the rest of the discussion shows four.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most(?) versions of `seq` will support outputting 0-padded values.

```
max=8525
for i in $(seq -w 2 $max); do
  python script.py -r "A$i"
done
```

Alternately, you can simply loop over the existing files and strip the extension.

```
for f in A*.txt; do
  f=${f%.txt}
  python script.py -r "$f"
done
```

Comment: I want to use it without file extention, I directly used `f` but that also comes with file extension. Any clue?

Comment: `f=${f%.txt}` should remove the extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `printf` to pad a number with leading zeros.

```
for ((i=1; i<=8525; ++i)); do
    printf -v filename "A%05i" "$i"
    python script.py -r "filename"
done
```

Of course, if the base filenames already exist, you can do

```
for f in A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png; do
    filename=${f%.png}
    python script.py -r "$filename"
done
```

which neatly avoids hardcoding the upper limit.

Comment: If you want only four digits after A, obviously use `"A%04i"` for the format string instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(find /path/to/your/files -type f -name "A?????");do python script.py -r "$file"; done
```

Comment: please check my update question. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I tried `for file in $(find training2017/ -type f -name "A?????");
do 
        #python script.py -r 
        echo "$file"; 
done` but it did not print anything

Comment: @Jhon how many digits are after "A" in the filenames ? , if it's 4, just change the file name pattern to `"A????"`

Comment: Why did you put `training2017/` in the `find` command? Nothing else here mentions a subdirectory like that.

Comment: @tripleee: All files are in `training2017` directory